# One of the objects has a weird looking shading on it in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

[image]Hi! I'm quite new to Cycles, and I have this problem here.
As you can see in the picture, one of the face parts has some kind of weird noise on it. Although the whole model has one material applied to it. Only this face part stands out for some reason.

In Eevee everything looks alright. But in Cycles it appears in this way. Any tips on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: maybe you have overlapping faces, take a look into your Outliner and check the visibilities in render. Or it can be 2 meshes overlapping in the same object

Comment: could you share the blend file?

Comment: May be a model hidden in 3d view but visible on render.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It was an overlapping faces issue after all. Never knew it was a thing, now I learned something new.